# How to find min and max time difference for rows in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following table structure and data

```
DriverName CarType      StartTime                  EndTime
---------- -------      ---------                  --------
DriverA    Honda        2014-09-29 14:32:03        2014-09-29 14:48:09
DriverA    Honda        2014-09-29 12:32:03        2014-09-29 14:32:09
DriverA    Honda        2014-09-29 10:32:03        2014-09-29 14:32:09

DriverA    Toyota        2014-09-29 10:32:03       2014-09-29 10:34:09
DriverA    Toyota        2014-09-29 9:32:03        2014-09-29 9:39:09
DriverA    Toyota        2014-09-29 8:32:03        2014-09-29 8:52:09
```

How can i get the worst best and average times in either seconds/minutes/or hours

```
DriverName  CarType     Worst                        Best      
---------- --------     ------                       -----     
DriverA     Honda       04:00:06 (4 hrs 6 seconds)    00:04:06 (4 minutes 3 seconds)
DriverA     Toyota      00:20:06 (4 hrs 6 seconds)    00:2:06 (20 minutes 3 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `timestampdiff()`

```
select DriverName, CarType,
       min(timestampdiff(second, StartTime, EndTime)) as Best,
       max(timestampdiff(second, StartTime, EndTime)) as Worst
from followingtable ft
group by DriverName, CarType;
```

If you want to show the value as a time format:

```
select DriverName, CarType,
       date_format(cast(0 as datetime) + interval min(timestampdiff(second, StartTime, EndTime,)) second,
                   '%H:%m:%d) as Best,
       date_format(cast(0 as datetime) + interval max(timestampdiff(second, StartTime, EndTime)) second,
                   '%H:%m:%d') as Worst
from followingtable ft
group by DriverName, CarType;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the best and worst you will want to get the date diff between the start time and end time and then get either the min or max of that respectively, then for the average you can basically do the same but using the average function. And finally you will want to group on the CarType and (I think) Driver  here is an example:

**Edit:**

It was pointed out that `DATEDIFF` does not function the way I expected, it will explicitly return the diff in days, I have updated the query to use `TIMEDIFF` instead, and I've also added the use of the `TIME_TO_SEC()` function to provide the output directly in seconds.

```
SELECT DriverName, 
       CarType, 
       MAX(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(EndTime,StartTime))) AS 'Worst', 
       MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(EndTime,StartTime))) AS 'Best', 
       AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(EndTime,StartTime))) AS 'Average'
GROUP BY DriverName, CarType
```

Comment: Max time difference will be worst right? I think you have it flipped.

Comment: @Anthony Did you try this query? You will get 0 everywhere because DATEDIFF calculates the difference in days. So I don't understand why you marked this answer as correct.

Comment: @Gervs,  thanks for pointing that out, I am used to MSSQL syntax and that thought had not occurred to me.